# zend framework posting json via rest

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, rest, http-post

Im trying to build an authenticating api with rest and also post a large object. Im talking about posting number of items such as some information about a car and its owner and store the information at a db level. is rest the way to go with this or use soap ? and if so any ideas how i can post json objects ? Much appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean post JSON objects? `json_encode` will convert object/array to Javascript Object Notation which is a string. Also, REST is much easier and simpler than SOAP... go with your current standards... or depending on the scale/distribution of your app... SOAP is more rigid (standard, harder to work with), REST is easier/faster to develop (flexible)

Comment: Or use Zend_Json::encode() / Zend_Json::decode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex & ArneRie (refer to comments) using, Zend_Json::encode() Zend_Json::decode()